# How to implement this type of behaviour in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://kavisha-pinto.sulekha.com/blog/post/2008/06/arranged-marriage-humour-poetry.htm

if you all see this link. left hand side we wil have one slide bar which open and we have some tabs in that conent.

is that any way that we can implement same behaviour in Jquery or javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/pullout). It even comes with a [demonstration website](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/sidecontent.html). Good luck!